# How to convert an image to a video stream functionally in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, browser, webrtc, mediastream

I would like to convert a image to a MediaStream in react, functionally as I have a requirement to merge the image MediaStream with my webcam MediaStream and download it.

However currently I am unable to do that and I have tried various methods including drawing to the canvas however I am not sure why that doesn’t work. Any suggestions with an example would be greatly helpful.